# What exactly does fork return?

Tags: c, linux, fork

> On success, the PID of the child
>   process is returned in the  parent’s 
>   thread  of  execution,  and  a  0  is
>          returned  in the child’s thread of execution.

```
p = fork();
```

I'm confused at its manual page,is `p` equal to `0` or `PID`?

Comment: Can someone include `getpid()` in the picture?
`getpid()` in child returns 0?

Comment: @Shrinidhi: So does `fork()`.

Comment: It is both pid and 0.  When fork is called, the program "splits" into two -- itself and its evil twin.  In the original program, it is 0.  In the evil twin program, it is the pid.

Comment: I would believe that a `fork` returns a small portion of food, but I could be wrong. ;-)

Comment: What is there to be confused about? The documentation you quoted is quite clear.

Answer (score 72):

I'm not sure how the manual can be any clearer!  `fork()` creates a new process, so you now have two **identical** processes.  To distinguish between them, the return value of `fork()` differs.  In the original process, you get the PID of the child process.  In the child process, you get 0.

So a canonical use is as follows:

```
p = fork();
if (0 == p)
{
    // We're the child process
}
else if (p > 0)
{
    // We're the parent process
}
else
{
    // We're the parent process, but child couldn't be created
}
```

Comment: `0` also means no process is created,right?Otherwise processes will be created recursively,never stop...

Comment: @compiler: no, both processes (the old one and the newly created one) continue execution **after** the call to `fork`.

Comment: @Joachim Sauer ,I mean no process is **created**,not saying **exit**

Comment: @compiler: There is no recursion.  As @Joachim says, the new process doesn't start from the beginning of main, it carries on directly after the `fork()` call.

Comment: I thinkk your code example is unclear, because you call fork two times (p = fork() and then 0 == fork() in the next line). Also it might be good to add there fork may also return -1 in which we still are in the parent process, as no child process could be created ;)

Comment: @Chris: Ah, yes, a typo!  Good catch.

Comment: If no process is created, that means `fork` *failed*, so it returns `-1`, not `0`, and sets `errno` appropriately.  It does this in the original process (which is not a parent, because no process was created).

Comment: A/ Does the new process start at the TOP of a new running copy of the script? Or immediately below the fork statement? How do you pass values to the forked process?

Comment: @Dennis: Both child and parent continue onwards from the call to fork.  There are lots of mechanisms for communicating between processes (pipes, FIFOs, sockets, ...)

Comment: @OliCharlesworth What happens to the program counter when we fork, where does the program counter points in the child process when we fork a new process?

Comment: @codeymodey He's answered that, a year before you asked. *Both child and parent continue onwards from the call to fork.*

Comment: This answer is ok when we have just one fork(), but I think its incomplete. What happens if we have multiple forks? The return of forks regarding other children will then return the pid, right? See this example https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/creating-multiple-process-using-fork/

Answer (score 35):

```
                             p = fork();
                        /* assume no errors */
                        /* you now have two */
                        /* programs running */
                         --------------------
      if (p > 0) {                |            if (p == 0) {
        printf("parent\n");       |              printf("child\n");
        ...                       |              ...
```

Answer (score 9):

Processes are structured in a ***directed tree*** where you only know your single-parent (`getppid()`). In short, `fork()` returns `-1` on error like many other system functions, non-zero value is useful for initiator of the fork call (the parent) to know its new-child pid.

Nothing is as good as example:

```
/* fork/getpid test */
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>     /* fork(), getpid() */
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    int pid;

    printf("Entry point: my pid is %d, parent pid is %d\n",
           getpid(), getppid());

    pid = fork();
    if (pid == 0) {
        printf("Child: my pid is %d, parent pid is %d\n",
               getpid(), getppid());
    }
    else if (pid > 0) {
        printf("Parent: my pid is %d, parent pid is %d, my child pid is %d\n",
               getpid(), getppid(), pid);
    }
    else {
        printf("Parent: oops! can not create a child (my pid is %d)\n",
               getpid());
    }

    return 0;
}
```

And the result (bash is pid 2249, in this case):

```
Entry point: my pid is 16051, parent pid is 2249
Parent: my pid is 16051, parent pid is 2249, my child pid is 16052
Child: my pid is 16052, parent pid is 16051
```

If you need to share some resources (files, parent pid, etc.) between parent and child, look at `clone()` (for GNU C library, and maybe others)

Answer (score 8):

This is the cool part. **It's equal to BOTH.**

Well, not really. But once `fork` returns, **you now have two copies of your program running!** Two processes. You can sort of think of them as alternate universes. In one, the return value is `0`. In the other, it's the `ID` of the new process!

Usually you will have something like this:

```
p = fork();
if (p == 0){
    printf("I am a child process!\n");
    //Do child things
}
else {
    printf("I am the parent process! Child is number %d\n", p);
    //Do parenty things
}
```

In this case, both strings will get printed, but by different processes!

Answer (score 8):

Once `fork` is executed, you have two processes. The call returns different values to each process.

If you do something like this

```
int f;
f = fork();
if (f == 0) {
  printf("I am the child\n");
} else {
  printf("I am the parent and the childs pid is %d\n",f);

}
```

You will see both the messages printed. They're being printed by two separate processes. This is they way you can differentiate between the two processes created.

Comment: When it returns 0,it means `fork` didn't create a process,right?

Comment: No. It means that you're in the child process. "Not creating a process" means that there will be just a single process. If a `-1` is returned, it means that no child was created. The man page indicates this.

Comment: when does it not create a child? if I use `fork()` in a while loop , will I ever be getting -1 value?

Comment: Could be for any reason. The `errno` is set if it returns -1 so you'll know why it failed.

Answer (score 2):

`fork()` is invoked in the parent process. Then a child process is spawned. By the time the child process spawns, `fork()` has finished its execution.

At this point, `fork()` is ready to return, but it returns a different value depending on whether it's in the parent or child. In the child process, it returns 0, and in the parent process/thread, it returns the child's process ID.

Comment: Do you mean `fork` evaluates to `NO Operation` in the child process?

Comment: @compiler: In this case, it has *no side effects*. But it does return differently depending on where it's being invoked.

Comment: No. Fork runs in the parent and then creates an extra process. The return value of fork, will be different in the two processes to distinguish between then two.

Comment: @Noufal Ibrahim,I know `0` means in child process,but does it also mean no extra process is created?

Comment: If you call `fork` once, one process will get created. I don't understand your question.

Comment: @Noufal Ibrahim: I think my answer was poorly-phrased. I edited it, maybe it makes more sense now.

Comment: @compiler no: fork returns -1, if no process is created.

Answer (score 1):

Fork creates a duplicate process and a new process context. When it returns a 0 value it means that a child process is running, but when it returns another value that means a parent process is running. We usually use wait statement so that a child process completes and parent process starts executing.

Answer (score -1):

I think that it works like this:
when pid = fork(), the code should be executed two times, one is in current process, one is in child process.
So it explains why if/else both execute.
And the order is, first current process, and then execute the child.

Comment: Order is not guaranteed (as far as I know).