# Child process always zero and always unique after fork()?

Tags: unix, pid, child-process

I've read man and elsewhere, but I'm struggling with this concept. The child process is always unique, but in any example of forking I've found the child's pid must = 0. What if there aremany children, they can't all be zero or they wouldn't be unique?

Comment: The child's pid is always 0 in its own environment. The parent process is the one that sees the real pid.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What exactly does fork return?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5577564/what-exactly-does-fork-return)

Comment: @RedAlert No, the child's pid is never 0. fork() _returns 0_ to the child to indicate that it is the child.

Answer (score 7):

The child process's pid is never zero.  `fork` returns zero to the child *to tell it that it is the child*.  The child process's pid, however, is the value that `fork` returns to the *parent*.  (Remember that `fork`, assuming it succeeds, *returns twice* -- once in the child, once in the parent.)  You can confirm this by writing a program that compares the result of `getpid` in the child to the value `fork` returns to the parent (with a little IPC).