# What's the difference between conditional !fork() and fork() > 0?

Tags: c, fork

I'm building a small test server. Here's the main part of it:

```
    while(1){
    addr_size = sizeof(their_addr);
    debug("still working here my friend?");
    new_sock = accept(sockfd,(struct sockaddr*)&their_addr,&addr_size);
    if(new_sock == -1){
        debug("cant find sockfd");
        continue;
    }
    debug("pid: %d",getpid());
    if(fork() >0){ 

        close(sockfd);
        while(1){ //this snippet works fine
            debug("start reading");
            read_some(new_sock,buffer);
            bstring data = RingBuffer_get_all(buffer);
            rs = process_request(&root,bdata(data)); 
            byte_send = send(new_sock,rs,strlen(rs),0);
        }

        close(new_sock);
        exit(0);    
    }
    close(new_sock);
}
```

When I run the server, whenever I close a client connection, the server also automatically exit. However, that did not happen when I change `fork() >0` to `!fork()`. What's the difference between `(fork() >0)` and `!fork()` when they can always create a new process here?

Comment: You *do* know what [`fork`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fork.html) returns?

Comment: postive integer for parent process and 0 for child process?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What exactly does fork return?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5577564/what-exactly-does-fork-return). Something being > 0 and !0 are logically different. Are you sure you want to fork a whole new process for every connection? This is like hiring a new employee just to serve one customer.

Comment: 0 to child is ok because the child can get its own pid thanks to `getpid()`. `!fork()` means basically `fork() == 0`, so you can see this is not the same as `fork() > 0`... (almost the opposite!)

Comment: @ggorlen i remember reading the copy-on-write characteristic of fork() so it might not be that resource demanding. What would you suggest instead of fork(), whatsoever?

Comment: Thread pool with a task queue might be worth looking into. It's pretty hard to say without knowing what your goals are, though.

Comment: Actually i'm just starting to learn socket programming, but i know that in this case i need multiple processes to use the same resource.

Answer (score 2):

`fork()` can return a positive number, a zero and a `-1` in case of the error.

By changing `fork() > 0` (which is True for positive numbers) to `! fork()` (which is True for non-zero) you have combined the successful execution of `fork()` with the failure case of `fork()` returning `-1`.

And no, they cannot **always** create a new process, sometimes things fail.

Comment: Well, but except for memory shortage,(which is impossible if i run only 1 or 2 connection), i can't see any other reason why fork would fail "here" (only in this case).

Comment: @VanTeoLe could you please print yourself a message every time `fork()` returns `-1` ?

Comment: If `fork` never failed, OP is correct, > 0 and !0 would be identical. But, as suggested here, OP probably ran into a negative value or they wouldn't be here asking what went wrong.

Comment: !fork() is the same as fork() == 0, i reckon. So the failure case is not included in !fork().