# Would be delighted to know about this question about fork

Tags: fork

just wanted to ask about this Fork question. I am really confused as to what the answer would be. If a process with PID 14 calls the fork function and new process will be created with PID 27.  In process 27, what is the return value of the fork function?

Comment: Did you check [the fork() man page](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/fork.2.html)?  "0 is returned in the child."

Comment: @NateEldredge thanks! Will sure do look into it now.

Comment: make the title of your question an actual question, perhaps something like "what is the return value of fork in the newly spawned process?"

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What exactly does fork return?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5577564/what-exactly-does-fork-return)